# Reading from log file and train a model for prediction

Tags: machine-learning

I have a file (access.log) from apache server which is my dataset. and I want to train a model on what is "Normal" and "Abnormal" in the file, so I manually added to some line a field that takes one of the two labels (normal | abnormal).

I put "Normal" ==> "0"

and "Abnormal" ==> "1"

Then I created a decision tree classifier

```
Features = [["GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", 55],["POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", 370]]
Labels = [1, 0]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(Features, Labels)
print clf.predict(["GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1",55])
```

The problem is that I can't do it this way as I am working with String values so the compiler shows an error saying:

> could not convert string to float: GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1

I really want to find a solution to manipulate the log file lines,  extract data for classifier, then train the model and predict the correct decision.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Decision Trees cannot deal with strings. To be able to learn from your log lines, you need to represent what is happening at the logs. You can use both categorical features and numerical features. This process is called feature engineering, which is part of preprocessing. I don't know what the number after yoru header represents but this could very well be a feature if it influences if it counts as 'Normal' or 'Abnormal'. I would extract a categorical feature for the type of request, like GET and POST. You could add a granular level that tries to represent what document the client requests. Just feeding strings to Machine Learning algorithms will not work (un)fortunately.

Comment: Yes giving the ML strings without any significations will not work for  sure, but I think that I have to devide the request itself and the URL into single parts then I think that the ML will be able to work with the data.

Comment: Not unless you turn it into categorical values, which you would need a LOT of training examples for to learn anything significant. Representing it in other ways that are much easier to learn from will work significantly better. There has been a lot of work done on ML with log files of webserver, take a look at those examples

Comment: Hi @Jan , Can you please give me reference to some of the previous work  on web server log files, because that really helps me to follow the technique they use.